# Null total spin and maximal entanglement

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Is it true that if the total spin of two entangled particles is 0 on all axes, then they must be maximally entangled?

Comment: Are you referring to spin 1/2 specifically, or to arbitrary spin for each particle? Similarly, by "total spin" I imagine you mean the expectation value of the total spin operator along a given axis?

Comment: Thanks, Emilio Pisanty. I mean that for any axis x, the sum of the spins of he particles along x must be 0 (e.g. because of conservation laws) and I was referring to any spin; but if it makes a difference, please, explain it so.

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't true. Probably the simplest example is two spin-1 particles, with both of them in the $L_z=0$ state,
$$
|\psi⟩=\left|1,0\right>\otimes\left|1,0\right>.
$$
This is completely separable, and it has zero expectation value for the total angular momentum along any axis, since
$$
 \left<\psi\middle|L_x\middle|\psi\right>
=\left<\psi\middle|L_y\middle|\psi\right>
=\left<\psi\middle|L_z\middle|\psi\right>
=0.
$$
If this is not what you mean then you need to ask a more precise question.